# Category wise product sale laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, e-commerce

I would to calculate the number of sale each category got and save it into an array as i have to display it in apex chart .

Here is a structure of my db

```
Category db:
category_name

Product db:
product_name;
category_id

OrderItem:
order_id;
product_id;
qty;
```

OrderItem relation :

```
public function product(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class,'product_id','id');
    }
```

I am bit confuse how to query that .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to do that you probably should implement the  *Has Many Through* relationship to get all orders made for each category, then you could make a method to count all items sold in that order, if that what you're after.

Here's how you could do that

in your *Category* model:

```
public function orderItems()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(OrderItem::class, Product::class);
}
```

this will give you access to the collection of orders made with that category, then you just will call like this:

```
$category->orderItems;
```

You can use that in your methods to make your calculations.

To read more about this, check the documentation of [has-many-through](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through).

Comment: Thanks for helping to understand it better , that relation worked for my case .